# Question about rails webservice and authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

What I am doing is rails web service API that let user create traveling log when they access any sites, by using firefox plugin.For this requirement I needed 2 things.

1. skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token in specific controller (Because I let user create it through API not the form, so I disable this).
2. user have to provided username and password every request (e.g. curl -u username:pass -d "..." http://localhost:3000/logs).

What I want to ask are

- can I made it easier by letting my
  firefox plugin ask for user login
  then use cookies, so no need to send
  username password every time with
  request.
- Does skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token is bad thing or necessary thing to do for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When Rails renders a form, it includes a hidden field with a long string (authenticity token). The `verify_authenticity_token` filter ensures that the user submitted a form that the server actually rendered (as opposed to forging a POST request, as hackers will do). If you use cookies and sessions you should really [read about how this works](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) and try to customize it to work with your plugin.

However, why not use [HTTP basic authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) instead? It's slightly faster than sending a cookie on every page view and should be much simpler to set up. As you say, you can have your plugin prompt for a username/password, and then send them with every request.

If you need to store user data in sessions, though, you'll have to use cookies.